# Deriving the confidence interval for the ratio of two differences between means

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Provided 3 datasets: x1, x2 and x3 (=x2 processed), 1D, same size and sampled from a normal distribution with equal variances, with x1 and x2 completely independent, do you think it would be possible to derive the confidence interval for the ratio:

`mean(x1) - mean(x2) / mean(x1) - mean(x3) (1)` ?

I know Fieller's theorem provides the confidence interval for the ratio `mean(A)/mean(B)`.

Given that `z = x - y is such that mean(z) = mean(x) - mean(y)` and z is normally distributed, could I adapt the Fieller's ratio to build the IC for:

`mean(Z_12)/mean(Z_13) = (1)`,

by simply adapting the MSEs and the degrees of freedom?

Thank in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. You might be better off with a bootstrap confidence interval, which relies on fewer assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am not sure to understand the general idea, should I compute the ratios values and bootstrap to approximate the IC ?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the idea. You could then compare to Fieller's CI.